# Escaping a keyword within a macro from graphql-client

Tags: rust, graphql

I am trying to use the graphql-client crate to make requests on a graphql schema that looks similar to this

```
enum AttributeType {
    // ...
}

type Attribute {
    name: String!
    type: AttributeType!
}
```

Using this

```
#[derive(GraphQLQuery)]
#[graphql(
    schema_path = "src/graphql/schema.graphql",
    query_path = "src/graphql/create_something.graphql"
)]
pub struct MutateSomethingModule;
```

When I try to use the graphql-client I get an error:

```
error: expected identifier, found keyword `type`
  --> src/x/mod.rs:14:10
   |
14 | #[derive(GraphQLQuery)]
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected identifier, found keyword
help: you can escape reserved keywords to use them as identifiers
   |
14 | #[derive(r#type)]
   |          ^^^^^^

error: proc-macro derive produced unparseable tokens
  --> src/x/mod.rs:14:10
   |
14 | #[derive(GraphQLQuery)]
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I am guessing this error message is complaining that I have the word `type` as an name is my schema and that I should escape it somehow. Based on the error message I tried replacing `type:` with `r#type:`, `r#"type"#` and some other similar variations.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based [on the code](https://github.com/graphql-rust/graphql-client/blob/708781ae761a1e062c3eea2c35b9bcb4f4b2f189/graphql_client_codegen/src/shared.rs#L39-L56), keywords have an underscore appended to them:

```
// List of keywords based on https://doc.rust-lang.org/grammar.html#keywords
let reserved = &[
    "abstract", "alignof", "as", "become", "box", "break", "const", "continue", "crate", "do",
    "else", "enum", "extern", "false", "final", "fn", "for", "if", "impl", "in", "let", "loop",
    "macro", "match", "mod", "move", "mut", "offsetof", "override", "priv", "proc", "pub",
    "pure", "ref", "return", "Self", "self", "sizeof", "static", "struct", "super", "trait",
    "true", "type", "typeof", "unsafe", "unsized", "use", "virtual", "where", "while", "yield",
];

if reserved.contains(&field_name) {
    let name_ident = Ident::new(&format!("{}_", field_name), Span::call_site());
    return quote! {
        #description
        #deprecation
        #[serde(rename = #field_name)]
        pub #name_ident: #field_type
    };
}
```

This means that `type` should be accessible as `type_`.

See also:

- [Handle all Rust keywords as field names in codegen (#94)](https://github.com/graphql-rust/graphql-client/issues/94)
- [Handle all keywords as field names in codegen (#96)](https://github.com/graphql-rust/graphql-client/pull/96)